# I'm getting "Resource temporarily unavailable" in aio_read completion routine for SIGEV_THREAD in RedHat

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, aio

Here is my design;

1) Init the AIO control block;

```
memset(&m_ReadBuffer, 0, sizeof(struct aiocb));
m_ReadBuffer.aio_fildes = dup(m_Socket);
m_ReadBuffer.aio_buf = NULL; /* Not yet */
m_ReadBuffer.aio_nbytes = 0;
m_ReadBuffer.aio_offset = 0;
m_ReadBuffer.aio_reqprio = 0;
m_ReadBuffer.aio_lio_opcode = LIO_READ;

m_ReadBuffer.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
m_ReadBuffer.aio_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = (void *) this;
m_ReadBuffer.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify_function = OnReadFinished;
m_ReadBuffer.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
```

2) Then fire an asynronous read operation;

```
int RetVal = aio_read(&m_ReadBuffer);

if (RetVal != 0)
    return false;
return true;
```

3) Here is my completion routine;

```
static void OnReadFinished(sigval_t pArg)
{
    ClassX *pTransport = (ClassX *) pArg.sival_ptr;

    // aio_error returns 0 if the request completed successfully
    int dwError = aio_error(&pTransport->m_ReadBuffer);
    int32_t cbTransferred = 0;

    // Did the request completed successfully
    if (dwError == 0) {
        // Cool, request completed, get the final retrun value.
        cbTransferred = aio_return(&pTransport->m_ReadBuffer);
    }
    else {
        // the request NOT completed, resheduling the reading process..
        // ***HERE: I'm getting "Resource unavailable temporarily***
        if (false == aio_read(&m_ReadBuffer))
            return;
    }

    // ... some codes ..
    return;
}
```

4) In AIO completion routine, I'm getting "Resource temporarily unavailable" repeatadly in idle time, but when the other side send something, I can read correct data. I think there is a bug in Linux kernel. If there is no data in socket, it should not call AIO completion routine with the "Resource temporarily unavailable" error. It wastes time unnecessarily..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we see the set-up for m_Socket and the life cycle of m_ReadBuffer?